# How to find the Lipschitz constant of the function below?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, machine-learning, lipschitz-functions

The function is $f(w)= \displaystyle\frac{1}{n} \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\left ( N \left ( \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{7} x _{ij}w_j\right) - G_i\right )^2$ where N is the sigmoid function. **w** is a vector with entries $w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_7 $

my attempt:

First, we have to find the gradient of the function:

$\nabla f(w) = \displaystyle\frac{2}{n}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\left ( N \left ( \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{7} x _{ij}w_j\right) - G_i\right ) \left( N '\left ( \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n} x _{ij}w_j\right)\right)\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^7 x_{ij}$ and $N'(x)= N(x)(1-N(x))$

$| \nabla f(w)-\nabla f(w')|\leq \displaystyle\frac{2}{n}\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^7 x_{ij}\left( \Bigg|\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\left ( N \left ( \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{7} x _{ij}w_j\right) - G_i\right ) \left( N '\left ( \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n} x _{ij}w_j\right)\right)-\\
  \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\left ( N \left ( \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{7} x _{ij}w_j'\right) - G_i\right ) \left( N '\left ( \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n} x _{ij}w_j'\right)\right)\Bigg| \right)$

I am stuck here. Anyone help??